# I want to use array function to convert array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have array like below.I want to convert this array but I want to use array function.is there any array function to convert below array

```
[name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Cash Crops
                [7] => Cereal Crops
                [12] => Vegetables
                [25] => Leafy Vegetables
                [28] => Vine Vegetables
            )
```

into this array

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Cash crops
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Pulse crops
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Oil seed crops
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Cereal Crops
            )
```

Comment: What functions have you tried?

Comment: No one is there any function?

Comment: What you have tried so far inorder to achieve or you are unaware of PHP array functions

Comment: I can write logic to convert it but I want array function

Comment: Post that logic within your question

Comment: @Uchiha Where did you get that hat?

Comment: @Amarnasan I don't know its a secret hat awarded by SO

Comment: Ever buddy is correct every one have given right solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) applied to the inner `name` array

```
$a = array(
    'name' => array(
        'Cash Crops','Cereal Crops','Vegetables','Leafy Vegetables','Vine Vegetables'
    )
);

$result = array();

array_walk($a['name'],
    function($value,$index) use (&$result){
        $result[] = array(
            'name' => $value
        );
});

print_r($result);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Cash Crops
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Cereal Crops
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vegetables
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Leafy Vegetables
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vine Vegetables
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way you can do this using a native php function is by using [**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
function twod($n)
{
    $res = array('name' => $n);
    return($res);
}

$a['name'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$new_array = array_map("twod", $a['name']);
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Please be sure to let the community know why you want something in a particular way instead of just saying "*I can write logic to convert it but I want array function*"

Comment: If you're going to copy something directly from the manual, at least make sure the information you're using is related to the question.

Comment: @Jon forgive my ignorance. Could you kindly explain to me, how this is not related to the question?

Comment: You changed the function correctly, but you left the second half of the code directly from the manual and didn't link `array_map` to the function name that you had changed `cube` to. ^^ Would also be better if in your array creation, you use the data provided by the question, and show the result in `print_r` format as well. ^^

Comment: Yes, I fixed the `"cube"` error before commenting that *facepalm*. Will keep in mind the advice about `print_r` the result. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: Not a problem! Happy to help, better answers help everyone. ^^

Comment: I want this function due to writing existing function is good practice rather than writing own logic

Comment: so is searching for array functions in [google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array%20functions%20in%20php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$oldarray = array()//your array with old data;
$newarray = convertArray($oldarray);

function convertArray($old){
    $new = array();
    foreach($old as $index=>$value)
    {
        $new[]['name'] = $value;
    }
    return $new;
}
```

This would convert it to your array.

Comment: I know logic.I want existing array function in php

Comment: I want this function due to writing existing function is good practice rather than writing logic

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner works with any 'name':

```
$tal = array_map(function($x) use($array)  {return array( array_keys($array)[0] => $x);}, $array[array_keys($array)[0]]);
```

Comment: what is that $x stands for